# Filtering time using last command on Solaris

Tags: shell, scripting, solaris

I'm connected on server using Solaris and need to filter only people who were connected there until 28.4 00:00.

How do I do that on Solaris? In bash I have -t option which does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris isn't fundamentally different from other *nix's. Moreover, looking at `bash -t` won't give you useful information in all cases.

Have you tried `last`?